# filtering mongodb documents based on the attributes with chaining the results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm developing a shopping website using MEAN stack.
consider having a Mongoose model named product with 12 different attributes like color, size, brand, etc. I want to add a feature for user to filter the products based on his choice on the properties and related values, like all the shopping websites. How can i query and find the products dynamically and chaining the results if the user make multiple choices.

Answer (score 1):

Call this function with something like: `{color: 'red', brand: 'company ltd'}`

```
function findProducts(options, callback) {
  let conditions = {};
  Objects.keys(options).forEach(key => {
      conditions[key] = new RegExp(options[key], 'i');
    });

    Products.find(conditions, callback);
  }
```

Comment: not getting my upvote for now, unless you remove js/html-snippet, cuz it's for working demo